# Missing message for key "registration.jsp.title"

Tags: java, jsp, struts, struts-1, xml-configuration

I was creating a simple registration app and I got stuck at a point.

The following is my `index.jsp` file

**`index.jsp`:**

```xml
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-html" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-logic" prefix="logic" %>

<html:html>

<head>
    <title><bean:message key="registration.jsp.title"/></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .error { color: red; font-weight:bold }
    </style>
</head>    
<body>
    
    <h1><bean:message key="registration.jsp.heading"/></h1>

    <logic:present name="registration-successful" scope="request">
        <h2>    
            <bean:message key="registration.jsp.registration-successful"/>   
            <bean:write name="registration-successful" property="userid" />
        </h2>
    </logic:present>

    <logic:notPresent name="registration-successful" scope="request">
        <html:form action="Registration.do" focus="userid">

            <dl>
                <dt><bean:message key="registration.jsp.prompt.userid"/></dt>            
                <dd>
                    <html:text property="userid" size="20" />
                    <span class="error"><html:errors property="userid" /></span>
                </dd>

                <dt><bean:message key="registration.jsp.prompt.password"/></dt>            
                <dd>
                    <html:text property="password" size="20" />
                    <span class="error"><html:errors property="password" /></span>    
                </dd>

                <dt><bean:message key="registration.jsp.prompt.password2"/></dt>            
                <dd><html:text property="password2" size="20" /></dd>

                <dt><html:submit property="submit" value="Submit"/>
                    <html:reset/>
                </dt>            
            </dl>
                    
        </html:form>
    </logic:notPresent>

</body>
</html:html>
```

I am having my `Application.properties` file contained in `/WEB-INF/resources` folder
and the following is the `struts-config.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.1//EN"
"http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_1.dtd">

<struts-config>

<form-beans>
    <form-bean name="RegistrationForm"            
type="net.thinksquared.registration.RegistrationForm"/>          
</form-beans>

<action-mappings>

    <action path="/Registration"
            type="net.thinksquared.registration.RegistrationAction"
            name="RegistrationForm"
            scope="request"
            validate="true"
            input="/index.jsp">

        <forward name="success" path="/index.jsp"/>

    </action>

</action-mappings>

<message-resources parameter="Application"/>

</struts-config>
```

Comment: If you're new to Struts, why are you starting with a version that's [officially EOL'd](http://struts.apache.org/struts1eol-announcement.html)? In any case, asking a question about a missing key without including the property file and the file's location makes it impossible to help.

Answer (score 0):

You should have `Application.properties` file in the src folder. This properties file should contain key-value pairs of messages that you get in the JSP via `<bean:message>` tag. For example

```
registration.jsp.title = My registration title
```

and you retrieve this message by the key that should be unique in the file using `key` attribute of the tag.